# Load UITabBarController from Nib

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How do we load a UITabBarController from NIB?

for UIViewControllers we could easily do this

```
        let viewController = SubclassOfViewController(nibName: "SubclassOfAViewController", bundle: nil);
```

But I could not find any similar method to load a UITabBarController which is from Nib

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Edit: I am not using Storyboards

Comment: Your SubclassOfAViewController is a subclass of UIVIewCOntroller. Similarly create a subclass of UITabViewCOntroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboard

```
 let tabbarController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubclassOfAViewController"];
```

where **SubclassOfAViewController** is identifier.

Else

```
let viewController = SubclassOfViewController(nibName: "SubclassOfAViewController", bundle: nil)
```

This method is fine. Since `UITabbarController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` there is no need of separate method here in subclass

Comment: Forgot to mention that i am using xibs and not storyboards. Thanks anyway